# 03 Suzuki GSXR 600 stator wires

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, stator

I ended up having to hard wire my stator after the plug burnt up. I've no issues except small oil leak from the stator cover. Well after taking it off time and time again and attempting to fix it I got the oil problem fixed but my bike was running the battery dead the hardwired that I did it come loose. So when I went to fix that I ended up rubbing off the markings I had on the wires. Now I don't how to wire it back. I can't find anything online that tells me what wire goes to what. Basically I have the three wires coming out of stator and three wires at they connected to but I don't know what order they go in. Help....

Answer (score 0):

Were the wires just one-to-one originally? If so then it may be a 3phase stator (wired in a delta format) and it should not matter which you connect to which.

Before you connect anything, check the resistance between each pair - you should have 3 values very similar if it is 3phase. If any of the values are significantly different then don’t connect or run until you find out more.

Also check for a reading between each wire and ground...